# How to set multiple Inline Variables in Replace Tokens tasks during release

Tags: azure-devops

I have a Replace Tokens task in my release and need to set multiple Inline Variables (not in the variables section of the pipeline or in any of the variable groups, variables are specific to this task).

The label says "Inline variables (YAML syntax) and I have determined that 'name':'value' will  work for a single variable, what should be used for multiple values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- task: qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@3
  displayName: 'Replace tokens in ./myfile'
  inputs:
    targetFiles: './some.Dockerfile'
    inlineVariables: |
      'Abc.Ref': 'Variable1' 
      'Cde.TT': 'Variable2'
```

Comment: I was thinking of setting it in the Azure UI, but it’s really the same thing. Upvoted and accepted.